# Sci-fi/fantasy book in which the main character and his friends could manipulate reality because they were a group of beings called celestial entities

Tags: story-identification, novel

So I don't have a lot to go on. It was a book I read in a middle school library around 2011.

I remember the main character would go to a skatepark with these friends and it turned out he and them could manipulate reality because they were actually a group of beings called celestial entities. I remember there's a scene of him traversing through different dimensions and at the end like demons are set to break out of theirs and into his.

If anyone has any clue of the name I'd be eternally grateful.